# App fabric without SQL Server whatsoever

Tags: sql-server, iis-7, appfabric

I got VPS with limited memory and my WCF service is hosted using AppFabric.

Since memory is limited and I am not using SQL server for anything other than AppFabric prerequisite im thinking about uninstalling SQL Server. (instance can eat up to 200mb memory at times). I am not using any DB related features of AppFabric like dashboard or caching. I like IIS extensions and simplicity for WCF service manipulations however, and I am thinking those do not require Sql Server actually.

I am unable to just try it out so wonder if someone has such experience, or can predict result of uninstalling SQL server on appfabric behaviour.

Comment: 2 silent close votes, care to say what did I do wrong?

Comment: Voted to close as 'not a real question' because I can't tell what you're trying to do from what you wrote. Could you try rewording your question? Are you uninstalling SQL Server or AppFabric?

Comment: oks indeed that might be unclear. I am thinking about uninstalling SQL Server, and would like to still have some of features that are added to IIS management console by AppFabric in relation to WCF services.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of uninstalling SQL Server you could just stop the SQL Server process. Set the process to manual startup.

That way if you need SQL Server in the future you can just start the process.

Comment: okay, question is more whether AppFabric will stay functional after that, its not definite. If we knew that AppFabric stays operational of-course disabling server process is fine option regarding memory savings.

Comment: You could test it, you can always just start the service again

Comment: server is in production currently and I got no test server available unfortunately thats why I am asking. Since AppFabric topic is fairly unpopular it would be better just to try it out myself I agree, if I could do that.

Comment: We run Appfabric caching without SQL Server, but we have configured appfabric to store configuration on a file share instead of SQL Server. You need to check your configuration.

Answer (score 0):

As @Shiraz Bhajiji illudes to if you are using SQLServer as the configuration store, you will need to reconfigure it to use file based configuration instead, it sounds like you are only using a single AppFabric instance, but if you are or needed to use multiple instances the config file would need to be accessible to all instances.

Again it isn't necessarily relevant to you, but if you have multiple app fabric instances, the sql server configuration option is a much more robust approach. With the file based approach, if you configure things incorrectly one app fabric node going down can take down the entire cluster. The SQLServer approach does represent a single point of failure however, if you are using clustering etc you can easily mitigate this. Again I appreciate I'm getting a little off topic here.